# ASP.NET MVC - Is there a way to simulate a ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, viewstate, state-management

I have the following situation... In a certain View, the user must select the initial hour, the final hour and the weekday. But, I can't save this informations to DB 'cause I need to save my whole page and I need the primary key of the primary table, but that's not the point.

So, while I don't save these data to DB, I'm saving to a Session. I was told to save to a cookie, but it appears that cookies have a size limit. So, I'm saving to a Session.

Buuuut, I was also told that I could save these informations (hours and weekday) to the user page, simulating a ASP.NET ViewState...

Does anyone know how to do this?? Does anyone know how to save temporarily these data withou using cookie or Session??

Thanks!!

Comment: Why the restriction on not using the Session?  I use the Session to store the output of the "steps" of a multi-step wizard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hidden input fields won't help?

```
<%= Html.Hidden(...) %>
```

Update (serializing an object to base64):

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, myObject); // myObject should be serializable.
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
```

When you want to fetch it back:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(hiddenFieldValue));
var myObject = (MyObjectType)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Make sure you validate the data stored in the field when you use it as the client might change it. `ViewState` takes care of this automatically.

*Side note:* ASP.NET uses [`LosFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter.aspx) instead of `BinaryFormatter` to serialize `ViewState` as it's more efficient or ASCII based serialization. You might want to consider that too.

Comment: I'm using hidden fields to some things... but how can I save a list of objects to a hidden field??

Comment: Binary serialize the object and convert the byte[] to base64 string.

Comment: Mehrdad, I've tried to do that but threw an error saying that my entity is not marked as serializable. I'm using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: By the way I suggest you not to serialize the entity class. Create a separate class with appropriate fields you need and make that serializable. In the final step, construct an entity based on the data in that class and submit it to DB.

Comment: In the code file associated with the DBML you can create a partial class that matches your entity and mark it as Serializable. However, as I suggested in my last comment, it's better to create a *new class* based on the data you want to store and make *that* [Serializable] instead.

Comment: This is becoming confusing hehehe!
For example, I have this entity SchedulePeriod and the fields hourInitial, hourEnd and weekday...

Comment: My last comment was your answer about makeing another class

Comment: Create your own class with those fields (forget the DBML classes). Mark that class as serializable. When you are ready to save it to DB, fill out a DBML class with data from your own. got it?

Comment: And this 'string result' I will send to my hidden field, right?

Comment: Cai use this to save a List of objects, like IList<SchedulePeriod> ??

Comment: This works for all serializable objects. List<T> is serializable if T itself is serializable. So yes, if you can store SchedulePeriod, you can also store List<SchedulePeriod>. BTW, it depends on the actual type of IList. Nothing can be said about IList<T> interface in general. List<T> works though.

Comment: For example, Mehrdad. User will select a initial hour, a final hour and a weekday and will click on 'save'. This will call a method that will serialize my new class that I created and pass it to a hidden. However, user will select another final and initial hour and a weekday and will save...

Comment: and this will also serialize my new class and pass it to the hidden field, but it will apss only the last 'save' action, am I right? The first 'save' the user did was lost, correct? That's why I've asked you about saving objects to a List.

Comment: Until now, what I was doing was to save a List to a Session and when user pick another initial and final hour and weekday, he will save these data and my method will check if Session already has a List. If so, this new data will be added to the List. But, Session is keeping what he is doing.

Comment: I think that if a serialize and save it to a hidden, it will save only the last 'save', because I will not have a place to keep the data entered before by the user...

Comment: Yes, this would work. You could also consider an AJAX style application that does all that stuff on the client and then submit it to server all at once.

Comment: I think I will have to pass hidden field value as parameter of my method, check it has something in it, if so Deserialize it and save the last data entered to this List, Serialize it again and pass it back to my hidden...

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do that. You could avoid postbacks by also doing the selection and adding to the list with javascript and sending the whole data list to server.

Comment: Does this 'string result' have a size limit??

Comment: 2GB :) Warning: if your data is so much that you're thinking about size limit, ViewState and similar stuff are probably not the way to go.

Comment: oww! 2GB?? My data is faaar below that! :-) I will test and tell you if it worked!

Comment: When I'm trying to deserialize it, it throws an error saying that my data lenght is invalid... it encrypts fine (at least, it seems), but when deserialize, it gives an error

Comment: I gave up... ti says the data length is invalid...
nevermind, I will try this in another time.
But, thanks for the help... :-)

Answer (score 3):

TempData["MyData"], mind you this will only last one round trip.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a javascript array on the client... and then transmit all the information when the user ultimately saves.

You have to work a little more, but in the end it pays off.

I heavily use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do stuff like that, it's easier than it seems.

Comment: Juan, I'm also using jQueryin the project. The problem is that this data is saving to a Session and I'm using jQuery Flexigrid to show them. My Session is feeding Flexigrid...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the data for that request and the next request I'd recommend using Tempdata, else I'd recommend using Mehrdad`s answer.