# How to maintain user session in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC.Can any budy explain me about session in MVC.I use session["user"] in .Net web application.Is it similar to it.

Comment: There is a similar question here at StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760872/asp-net-mvc-and-session

Answer (score 2):

here is the  link that explains how to use session in MVC

[Session variables in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc)

here is your answer ... just one more point that before you post a question do search for the similar question on the site or web else your question will be closed down ...