# What type of objects can be sent back to an action Method using Html.Hidden()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1) Let's say I've this form:

```
<% Using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%= Html.Hidden("myObject", 
                   (cast to the appropriate type)ViewData["KeyForMyObject"] %>     
<input type = "submit" "Submit Object">
<% } %>
```

2) Here's the Action which's supposed to intercept the value of the object

```
public ActionResult MyAction(Type myObject)
{
    //Do Something with the object 
}
```

**Here's my question:** What type of objects the Hidden field can support?

In fact, when **ViewData["KeyForMyObject"]** contains a string, int, or bool, **myAction** is able to retrieve the value.

But, when it comes to objects, such as **List**, and **dictionary**, nothing happens. When I debug to check the local values, I see null for **Type myObject** in the MyMethod.

So what are the rules in MVC when it comes to a List or Dictionary?

---

EDIT

To make things simpler, can I write something like this

```
<%= Html.Hidden("contactDic", (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewData["contacts"]) %>
```

and expect to retrieve the dictionary in the action Method like this

```
public ActionResult myMethod(Dictionary<string, string> contactDic)
{
    // Do something with the dictionary
}
```

Thanks for Helping

Answer (score 0):

The notation for lists is a bit more complex.

Something like  `[0].Title` if you want the first item Title

See http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The present question is one of many I've asked. They all have one thing in common: I was trying to keep the state of my data (**Multisteps/Wizard like application**). So I was trying to use statement such as **ModelState.Clear()** abusively to clear the content of the ViewData.

Now I realize that I was fighting the way ViewData is supposed to work (e.i. MVC itself). To conclude, to keep the state of my objects, I need to serialize/deserialize object.

The best sample I found is the **Multisteps Wizard p.396-406 "Pro ASP.NET MVC/Steve Sanderson/Apress**"

Also see [how to stimulate a ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669492/asp-net-mvc-is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-viewstate).

It looks like I just found out what I was looking for without knowing how to express myself.

Thanks